# Generate Swagger Doc in .net Framework 4.8 from separate project

Tags: swagger, webapi, .net-4.8

Our solution is pretty unusual.
We have a console built in .Net Framework 4.8 which launches the WebAPI and other stuff.
The APIs are in a separate .Net Framework 4.8 project.

How can I generate swagger doc for my APIs?
I didn't find any doc on the internet that can help me.